# Unity3D C# Timer Displaying in Milliseconds

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make it change the .text to the following format:

00:00:00

But instead I get
0:00.00000
What do I need to change in-order to correct my code?

```
private void Update()
{
    if (!chestButton.IsInteractable ()) 
    {
        if (IsChestReady ()) {
            chestButton.interactable = true;
            chestTimer.SetActive (false);
            chestTimerBg.SetActive (false);
            newGift.SetActive (true);
            return;
        }
        //Set Timer
        ulong diff = ((ulong)DateTime.Now.Ticks - lastChestOpen);
        ulong m = diff / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
        float secondsLeft = (float)(msToWait - m) / 1000.0f;

        string r = " ";
        //Hours
        r += ((int)secondsLeft / 3600).ToString() + ": ";
        secondsLeft -= ((int)secondsLeft / 3600) * 3600;
        //Minutes
        r += ((int)secondsLeft / 60).ToString();
        //Seconds
        r += (secondsLeft % 60).ToString();
        chestTimerTxt.text = r;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You forgot the int conversion for the seconds.

```
r += ((int)secondsLeft % 60).ToString();
```

However, the easiest way to do what you want is to use TimeSpan.

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds((int)secondsLeft);
chestTimerTxt.text = ts.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
```

If you try to do it manually the way you're doing, you will also have to check for cases where you need to add an extra 0 or not - such as if secondsLeft = 50 vs 9. If you still want to do it that way, then try converting secondsLeft to an Int before doing all your calculations (round up or down using Math.Round). You also need to add a ":" between the minutes and the seconds.